# how correctly set up checklist-model directive in my angular js app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, checklist-model

I'm a noob with node.js/grunt world, so i am sorry if the question is pretty dumb...

I have an angular.js project that works with yeoman/grunt, 
now what i want to do is to include a directive, specifically [this one](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model),

But i'm not sure how to install it!

i have:

-used the command npm install checklist-model from my command prompt

-linked the script inside index.html file

```
<script src='node_modules/checklist-model/checklist-model.js'></script>
```

-and add dependency in my app

```
var app = angular.module('generaPreventivoApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'checklist-model'
]);
```

the console give me the following error:

```
  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module checklist-model due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'checklist-model' is not available
```

how can i correctly set up?

Comment: script path reference seems to be incorrect as It will try to resolve the node_modules path relative to index.html and probably node_modules will be one directory up. is your rest of the angular library in `node_modules` folder? You can either use bower or simply copy the js file in your script folder and modify the path in index.html accordingly.

Comment: the path is correct.. Thr other scripts are linked to 

<script src='node_modules/checklist-model/checklist-model.js'></script>

so same root.

Answer (score 1):

i tried to install using bower, so:

bower install checklist-model --save

**my bower  updated:**

```
{
"name": "genera-preventivo",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.4.0",
"bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
"angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
"angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
"angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
"angular-route": "^1.4.0",
"angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
"checklist-model": "^0.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
},
"appPath": "app",
"moduleName": "generaPreventivoApp",
"overrides": {
  "bootstrap": {
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
}
}
}
```

**index.html**

```
    <script src="bower_components/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>
```

**APP.js**

```
var app = angular.module('generaPreventivoApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'checklist-model'
```

])